# Is it necessary to check `ValueTask.IsCompleted` for performance?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task, valuetask

- case 1:

```
bool result = await DoAsync();
```

- case 2:

```
ValueTask<bool> task = DoAsync();
bool result = task.IsCompleted ? task.Result : await task;
```

With `case 1` and `case 2` above,
can anyone say `case 2` is better for performance(cpu, memory, etc.)?
Or, is `task.IsCompleted` just duplicated and redundant?

Comment: This check is redundant. See this [article](https://www.markopapic.com/csharp-under-the-hood-async-await/).

Comment: @viktor very detailed and helpful article, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *really know for sure*, you'd need to measure using a suitable benchmark. However, I would not *expect* this to have any significant impact, since `await` *already* does exactly that - albeit via `GetAwaiter()` (which doesn't allocate). It could actually make the truly async scenario *worse*.

Something similar to this optimization *is* common in library code, but is typically used to *avoid the state machine entirely* when a result is likely to be synchronous a lot of the time; for example:

```cs
var pending = DoAsync(); // note: not awaited; this is a [Value]Task[<T>]
return pending.IsCompletedSuccessfully
    ? new ValueTask<Foo>(PostProcess(pending.Result))
    : Awaited(pending);

static async ValueTask<Foo> Awaited(ValueTask<Bar> pending)
    => PostProcess(await pending.ConfigureAwait(false));
```

The key point here is that the original method is **not `async`** in this scenario, so we only pay any `async` overhead in the truly async path (or in the failure case, to standardise the error stack).

---

Here's a [`sharplab.io` link](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) that shows what is going on with this optimization; on the right, you can see the optimized version that doesn't use `async`, which comes out as:

```cs
    public ValueTask<Foo> ExampleAsync()
    {
        ValueTask<Bar> pending = DoAsync();
        if (!pending.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
        {
            return <ExampleAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(pending);
        }
        return new ValueTask<Foo>(PostProcess(pending.Result));
    }
```

The `Awaited` method, however is *all of*:

```cs
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<<ExampleAsync>g__Awaited|0_0>d))]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static ValueTask<Foo> <ExampleAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(ValueTask<Bar> pending)
    {
        <<ExampleAsync>g__Awaited|0_0>d stateMachine = default(<<ExampleAsync>g__Awaited|0_0>d);
        stateMachine.pending = pending;
        stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder<Foo>.Create();
        stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
        stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
        return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private struct <<ExampleAsync>g__Awaited|0_0>d : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        public int <>1__state;

        public AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder<Foo> <>t__builder;

        public ValueTask<Bar> pending;

        private ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<Bar>.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter <>u__1;

        private void MoveNext()
        {
            int num = <>1__state;
            Foo result;
            try
            {
                ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<Bar>.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter awaiter;
                if (num != 0)
                {
                    awaiter = pending.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();
                    if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        num = (<>1__state = 0);
                        <>u__1 = awaiter;
                        <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    awaiter = <>u__1;
                    <>u__1 = default(ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<Bar>.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter);
                    num = (<>1__state = -1);
                }
                result = PostProcess(awaiter.GetResult());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                <>1__state = -2;
                <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
        }

        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
            this.MoveNext();
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
            <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
        }

        void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
            //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
            this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could understand your first paragraph, thank you very much. By the way, could you explain more about 'It could actually make the truly async scenario worse' ? Does your '_worse_' mean 'erroneous', or just 'redundant' ? And, pardon me, I couldn't understand your second paragraph, your example seems for me the same as my `case 2`: Your `PostProcess` will be called in both branches, so that i think just `return Awaited(DoAsync());` would be enough.

Comment: @ALittleDiff on "worse" I meant performance wise; it adds an extra (duplicated) fetch, test and branch; that might not be a lot, but in some performance critical cases this can matter; usually it won't be measurably different, though. On the second part: yes, it is *intentional* that we do the same things either way - the important difference is that we've avoided the state machine overhead in the happy path. The code that the compiler adds in the `Awaited` method is a lot more than you might expect, and can have a measurable overhead in some scenarios like IO loops.

Comment: Could you confirm my understanding, please? Then can I say "With my `case 2`, the happy path(`task.Result`) can avoid the state machine overhead, and the unhappy path(`await task`) cannot avoid it", and "but just `await task` is not heavy, whereas your `PostProcess(await pending)` is a lot more heavy" ?

Comment: "but just await task is not heavy" oh, it is heavy; it is *surprisingly* heavy; it might look like one line of code to you, but that's a *huge* amount of code; note that `PostProcess` is irrelevant here since we do exactly the same code there either way; here's a breakdown of what is actually happening - the point of the optimization is that in the path where it turns out to be synchronous, we don't touch *any* of that huge generated async state machine overhead (edit: link moved to post body)

Comment: Ok, if `await task` might be heavy, then can I say `case 2` is better for performance than `case 1` ? I might misunderstand your first paragraph.. I've taken your first paragraph as `case 2` would not be necessary.

Comment: Both of the comment of @viktor and the answer of @mortb say "`case 1` is enough and `case 2` is redundant", so that I thought `case 1` would also avoid `await` overhead _behind the scenes_, and I would not need explicit `task.IsCompleted` check. But do you mean I misunderstood it?

Comment: I'm totally confused now, it seems you say "`case 2` is redundant and even _worse_" in the first paragraph, but you also say "only `case 2` can avoid _heavy overhead_" in the second paragraph(and the following comments). Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @ALittlsDiff ok, let me reset: special-casing the "is completed" scenario is only useful if you're also avoiding the `await`. The problem with "case 2" is that it does this check, but also has an `await`. It doesn't matter that we won't be reaching it: the fact that an `await` exists in the method means that the compiler is going to massively rewrite the method. So: if you want the await, don't bother checking "is completed": the `await` will do that anyway. And if your goal is to special-case/optimize the sync path, you really want to move the `await` out of the method.

Comment: Very clear explanation! I think I found out what I misunderstood, One more question(I hope this would be the last one), I've tried to apply your example code into mine but failed to compile it in `Awaited(pending)`: "error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<bool>' to 'bool'". When I changed it to `Awaited(pending).Result`, it was compiled successfully. Do I really need `.Result` part for `Awaited(pending)` ?

Comment: For reference, my whole test code looks like: `bool Foo() { ValueTask<bool> task = DoAsync(); if (task.IsCompleted) { return task.Result; } else { return Awaited(task).Result; }}`

Comment: @ALittleDiff did you take the `async` modifier off the method? If you're doing to optimized path, then you *do not* have the fast path method marked `async`. However, I'm more concerned by the fact that `Foo()` appears to return `bool`, not `ValueTask<bool>` or `Task<bool>` (or some other awaitable). You *can't do that* - that's "sync over async", and is a very bad idea for many many reasons.

Comment: Ok, but I meet the the same error even when I changed the method to `async Task<bool> FooAsync()`. The compiler still require `.Result` .

Comment: Full code: `async Task<bool> FooAsync() { ValueTask<bool> task = DoAsync(); if (task.IsCompleted) { return task.Result; } else { return Awaited(task).Result; } }`

Comment: @ALittleDiff look once again at the sharplab.io example I linked earlier; the correct approach would be (note no `async`): `ValueTask<bool> FooAsync() { ValueTask<bool> task = DoAsync(); if (task.IsCompleted) { return new ValueTask<bool>(task.Result); } else { return Awaited(task); } }` - however, if you're not actually doing any post-processing of the result, frankly, it becomes just `ValueTask<bool> FooAsync() { return DoAsync(); }`

Comment: Cleared. I really appreciate your patience. By the way, I need to confess I couldn't connect to your `sharplab.io` link.. It seems broken.

Comment: @ALittleDiff dammit, the shortener was working yesterday; I'll edit the link into the post (it is too long for comments)

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 is fine. You'd use task.IsCompeted if you don't use `await` at all.

Comment: Could you share your opinion about the typical example of @MarcGravell ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812168/3687475 )?

Comment: @ALittleDiff important clarification: it isn't "typical code"; it is an optimization sometimes used in performance critical **library** code, which (when needed) *typically* is implemented like in the example shown. In most *application* code, you'd just `await` the thing and move on. These are the annoying details that library code hides from application code, so that application code just worries about the big picture. The important difference is that library code might encapsulate a lot of async IO calls (sometimes hundreds or thousands) in what the application just sees as one method call.

Comment: @ALittleDiff: As I see it case one is the most readable and I focus on writing code that is easy to understand for most other developers. Of course there is a small performance penalty, but if you start using `Task`s without `await` the code quickly gets complicated and you need to have a deeper understanding of how `Task`s are executed to reason about the code. It would be ok to make the code less readable if the code is run in a way that makes the small performance loss noticeable. I believe that is not the case for the majority of programs.

Comment: I also totally agree with you!